# Requirement to read from the standard input

Tags: python

I have an assignment and there is in the beginning a requirement. The assignments requires you to read from the standard input. Do not read directly from the example files, as the automated testing system expects you to read from the standard input. Instead, process the lines as follows:

```
import sys
for l in sys.stdin.read().splitlines():
   pass # do stuff with each line
```

If the the file is "example.txt" what do they mean and how do I need to do that?

Comment: You can use command-line redirection to send the file's contents to the script as `stdin`. i.e. `python myscript.py <example.txt` The code you already have in your question will read the the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting problem. I believe @martineau is right.
(I can't comment because I don't have enough reputation, but maybe I can answer??)

To make @martineau's comment more concrete, suppose you replace `pass` with a line like:

```
print (len(line), line)
```

and have an example file `gettysburg.txt` with this text:

```
Four score and seven years ago
our fathers brought forth upon this continent,
a new nation, conceived in Liberty,
and dedicated to the proposition
that all men are created equal.
```

Then when you run `python myscript.py <gettysburg.txt`
the first couple lines would be:

```
30 Four score and seven years ago
46 our fathers brought forth upon this continent,
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. One advantage of this approach is that there's no need to hardcode the input file's name into the script itself.

Answer (score 0):

It could mean `fileinput.input()`

```
import fileinput
 
 
with fileinput.input(files = ('sample.txt', 'no.txt')) as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

OR simply:

```
file = open("sample.txt", "r")
lines = readlines()
```

Comment: Hi, thank you! What does the 'no.txt' means? in the file there is some 4 lines with names and grades of the names

Comment: it simply shows that you can open and read multiple files with that approach

Comment: Alright, Thankss, I checked in the system, but the system said I need to use the code:
import sys
for l in sys.stdin.read().splitlines():
   pass # do stuff with each line